# Adding to very large numbers using stack

Tags: c++, string, char, stack, addition

i am a novice to C++ , I was trying to write this program for adding two very large numbers using strings but the program is not working correctly and I can't get what's wrong with it , please help me with this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    stack <char> a1;
    stack<char> a2;
    stack<int> result;
    stack<int> temp;
    int carry = 0;
    string num1;
    string num2;
    cout << "Enter first number (both numbers should have equal digits)" << endl;
    getline(cin, num1);
    cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
    getline(cin, num2);

    
    for (int i = num1.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        a1.push(num1[i]);
        
        a2.push(num2[i]);
        

    }

    while (!a1.empty() && !a2.empty()) {
            int element = (int)a1.top() + (int)a2.top() + carry;
         cout << element;

        if (element > 10) {
            element %= 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        result.push(element);
        cout << result.top() << endl;
        a1.pop();
        a2.pop();


    }
    string abc;

    while (!result.empty()) {
        temp.push(result.top());
        result.pop();
        abc += temp.top();
    }

    cout << abc;


}
```

I know i have definitely made a logical mistake , but i can't get it , can anyone please guide me?
the following is the output am getting

[image]

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger and step through your code. Actually it's a good idea to rethink your code and build and test one part at a time.

Comment: There are two fundamental mistakes here. One, is that this can be implemented much simpler, without using any stacks. But the real bug is that you'll be surprised to learn that if, for example, the last digit of one of the numbers was 1, the number on the top of the stack will not be 1. If you add some debugging statements to your code you should be able to figure out the answer by yourself. The key to becoming an experienced C++ developer is to learn how to debug your own code, and this is an excellent learning opportunity for that.

Comment: There are several errors in the code. for one thing you are storing the ascii value of the digits in your stacks, another thing is that you are pushing the digits on the stack in reverse order so the usefulness of the stack is lost. All this you would see if you used a debugger

Comment: How do i get rid of this then? like how i get to store actual numbers instead of ASCII equivalents? I resolved my issue of backwards loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking, why stacks should be used. My guess is that you did this, because the numbers must be processed from right to left.

Additionally, you have obiously a challenge with strings with a different length.

But both problems can be solved easily. Let us start with the different length strings.

If 2 strings have a different length, we can pad (fill in) the shorter string with leading `0's. How many leading '0s' do we need to add? Right, the delta of the lengths.

And for inserting characters in a string at a certain position, we have the function [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).

So, the code for that will look like this:

```
                if (numberAsString1.length() < numberAsString2.length())
                    numberAsString1.insert(0, numberAsString2.length() - numberAsString2.length(), '0');
                else
                    numberAsString2.insert(0, numberAsString1.length() - numberAsString2.length(), '0');
```

This is rather straightforward.

The result will always be 2 strings with equal length. With entering "1234" and "9", we will get: "1234" and "0009".

This makes the next task easier.

---

Now that we have 2 equal length strings, we can "add", like we learned in school.

We go from right to left, by starting with the highest possible index of a character in the string. This is always length-1.

For calculating the sum, we need first to subtract the ASCII code for '0' from the characters in the string, because the string contains not integer numbers, but characters. For example "123" consists of '1', '2', '3' and not of 1,2,3.

Suming up is then easy: digit + digit + carry.

The resulting digit is always the `sum % 10`. And the next carry is always `sum / 10`. Example 1: `3+5=8  8%10=8  8/10=0`. Example 2: `9+8=17  17%10=7  17/10=1`.

So, also this is rather simple.

After we worked on all digits of the strings, there maybe still a set carry. This we will then add to the string.

Adding digits will be done in any case using the instert function. Because we want to insert digits on the left side of the resulting string.

So, with working from right to left, using correct indices and the insert function, we do not have the need for a stack.

With a lot of input checking, the whole function would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {

    // Give instruction to user
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter 2 positive interger numbers:\n";

    // Here we will store the user input
    std::string numberAsString1{}, numberAsString2{};

    // Get strings from user and check, if that worked
    if (std::cin >> numberAsString1 >> numberAsString2) {

        // Check if all characters in string 1 are digits
        if (std::all_of(numberAsString1.begin(), numberAsString1.end(), std::isdigit)) {

            // Check if all characters in string 2 are digits
            if (std::all_of(numberAsString2.begin(), numberAsString2.end(), std::isdigit)) {

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Here we will store the calculated result
                std::string result{};
                // Temporary helpers
                unsigned int carry{};

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Make strings equal length. Pad with leading '0' s
                if (numberAsString1.length() < numberAsString2.length())
                    numberAsString1.insert(0, numberAsString2.length() - numberAsString2.length(), '0');
                else
                    numberAsString2.insert(0, numberAsString1.length() - numberAsString2.length(), '0');

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Iterate over all digits from right to left
                for (int i = numberAsString1.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {

                    // Calculate the sum
                    const int sum = numberAsString1[i]-'0' + numberAsString2[i] - '0' + carry;

                    // Get the carry bit in case of overflow
                    carry = sum / 10;

                    // Save the resulting digit
                    result.insert(0, 1, sum % 10 + '0');
                }
                // handle last carry bit
                if (carry) result.insert(0, 1, '1');

                // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Show result
                std::cout << "\n\nSum: " << result << '\n';
            }
            else std::cerr << "\n\nError: number 1 contains illegal characters\n";
        }
        else std::cerr << "\n\nError: number 2 contains illegal characters\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem with input\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain , why do we have to add '0', like i understand its for converting ASCII equivalents back to integer but  how is it working ? what it does\?

Comment: If you have an integer digit, let's say 5 it will not be shown as a readable character. If you look at here: https://www.virtualuniversity.ch/software/ascii/index.html, then you will see that it will probaly shown as a '|'. So if you want to show a character for number 5, which we will denote as '5' (single quotes), then we see in the ASCII table that we nueed a value of 53. So, we need to add to all numbers 48 or, written as character '0'. Therefore, we add to all calculated digit values '0' (48) and get the character that we want. And this will be inserted into the string.

Comment: can you also guide me a bit , how do i make it possible using stacks? like i want to make this an application of stack using my logic or by changing it a bit

Comment: sorry to bother you again but so is this that '5' equal 53 and '0' equals 48 an when we do this subtraction and assign it to an int it subtracts their integer equivalent 53-48 and gives us 5 ? right? and also instead of this why is typecasting like(int) or atoi function etc. are not working?